# What is the string format of the Asp.net SessionID?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, string-formatting, sessionid

I want to use the `Session.SessionID` as file name and query string in URL. I want to know if its format is suitable for these applications. For example you can not use `'?'` or `'<'` characters in a file name.

Is SessionID format string safe for file names and query strings?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From [this MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionidmanager.aspx)

```
"The ASP.NET session identifier is a randomly generated number encoded into a 
 24-character string consisting of lowercase characters from a to z and numbers 
 from 0 to 5."
```

So the answer is, Yes & it's safe to be used for file names and query strings

Answer (score 0):

Session ID is ok to use its just a string with no weird characters

Comment: Is there any reference about this?

Comment: "The session ID is returned as a LONG data type"